# Karma Jasmine Async Testing not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm currently trying to test something that uses async tasks, concrete I have the following lines:

```
setTimeout(function(){
 //do something
},300);
```

The `setTimeout` is in a function as well. Now in my test, I call this function, that contains the setTimeout and I'm getting an error, that the element I'm using inside of `setTimeout` is not defined/null.

Now I tried out various ways but none seems to work.

I tried to include `done` into my `it` and put the function call in a setTimeout, just like so:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  callTheFunctionThatContainsTheTimeout();
  done();
});
```

Doesn't work. I tried to import `$timeout` (I'm actually using angular), and then put the function call in `$timeout` and put a `$timeout.flush` afterwards, but nothing works. Does anybody know what I do wrong and how I can do it right?

Comment: You can't use standalone timeouts in async jasmine testing... look at [their API docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support). You need to pass in the `done` function, and call done inside the timeout.

Comment: either I understand you wrong or you understood me wrong.. I'm already passing done into the it and then calling after I called the function that uses setTimeout. Did I understand something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure? It's not apparent in your example.

Comment: Actually that's what the second code snippet I provided is meant to do, so around this there is a `it('something to do', function(done){});` I'm right that I doesn't need to modify the original code but only use `done` in the test, right?

Comment: I think so. Check my [codepen example](https://codepen.io/evolutionxbox/pen/kXzkAp), just to make sure.

Comment: Exactly, except that before calling done I'm calling the function that originally uses setTimeout

Comment: You could try pausing the jasmine "clock"

Comment: What would this do and how would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you really intended to call a function that contains the timeout from *inside* another timeout, but anyway this is feasible, if you are allowed to change the `callTheFunctionThatContainsTheTimeout` function.

The function would look something like:

```
function callTheFunctionThatContainsTheTimeout(callback) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('ooo'); // do something here
    callback(); // execute a callback function
  },300);
}
```

And the test would be like:

```
it('something to do', function(done){
  setTimeout(function(){
    callTheFunctionThatContainsTheTimeout(function(){ // the callback function
      expect(2+2).toEqual(4); // do your tests here
      done();
    });
  },200);
});
```

And if you do not need a second timeout, the test would look like:

```
it('something to do', function(done){
  callTheFunctionThatContainsTheTimeout(function(){ // the callback function
    expect(2+2).toEqual(4); // do your test here
    done();
  });
 });
```